# How to use React-Bootstrap Nav.Link in Next.JS properly?

Tags: next.js, navbar, react-bootstrap, hydration

## The Question

What is the correct way to implement the React-Bootstrap `<Nav.Link>` in Next.JS? I read that you should wrap it like this: `<Link href="#home" passHref><Nav.Link>Home</Nav.Link></Link>`. When I tried this however, I got a hydration error that I looked up, and it said it occurs with an `<a>` in an `<a>`

I tried that, however, I got a hydration error that I looked up, and it said it occurs with an `<a>` in an `<a>`. Any ideas? Thanks!